# oracle sql dynamic insert statement

Tags: oracle, function, insert

I have an oracle function that has a parameter which defines in which column the value should be inserted, e.g.

```
 function something(p_value, p_nr) 
 is 
   ...
 begin
   if p_nr = 1 then
       insert into A (column1) (p_value);
   else if p_nr = 2 then
       insert into A (column2) (p_value);
   ...
   end if;
```

I have a couple of values to enter in the table and only this value should be inserted dynamically. Is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```
insert into A (column1, column2)
values (case when p_nr = 1 then p_value end,
    case when p_nr = 2 then p_value end);
```

That would put the value in one of the two columns, and null in the other; which way round depends on the flag value. (I've omitted the implied `else null` from both cases, but the intent might be clearer with it in).

Since that's now plain SQL it might not even need to be wrapped in a function (or procedure), depending what else you're doing.

Answer (score 3):

If your table structure defines default values for columns, you might also consider conditional insert:

```
insert all
when :p_nr = 1 then into A( col1 ) values( p_value )
when :p_nr = 2 then into A( col2 ) values( p_value )
when :p_nr = 3 then into A( col3 ) values( p_value )
select :p_value as p_value from dual
;
```

The advantage is that this query honors default values, look at an example:

```
create table A(
  col1 varchar2( 10 ) default 'default 1',
  col2 varchar2( 10 ) default 'default 2',
  col3 varchar2( 10 ) default 'default 3'
);

variable p_nr number
variable p_value varchar2( 100 )

exec :p_nr:=2
exec :p_value:='value'

insert into A (col1, col2, col3)
values (case when :p_nr = 1 then :p_value end,
        case when :p_nr = 2 then :p_value end,
        case when :p_nr = 3 then :p_value end);

select * from A;

COL1       COL2       COL3     
---------- ---------- ----------
           value
```

and:

```
rollback;

insert all
when :p_nr = 1 then into A( col1 ) values( p_value )
when :p_nr = 2 then into A( col2 ) values( p_value )
when :p_nr = 3 then into A( col3 ) values( p_value )
select :p_value as p_value from dual
;
select * from A;

COL1       COL2       COL3     
---------- ---------- ----------
default 1  value      default 3
```